# Cypress Test If Element Is Not Draggable

Tags: cypress

let's say I have an element called `.item`. I want to test that it is not draggable in cypress.

I'm have a calendar in react, and I want to assert that the historic items are not draggable. The package I'm using for the callendar is called react full calendar

Until now, I have the following code:

```
it("should not be draggable(editable)", () => {
    // visit /schedule
    cy.visit("/schedule").waitForGraphQL();

    // Click prev button
    cy.get(controls.week.prevButton()).click().waitForGraphQL();
});
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What's the HTML, what's the test so far, what error does it give?

Comment: There's no error, I have no idea how to start. I'm using react

Comment: Ok, please also show the html and if you use a React library which one.

Comment: @Fody I'm using react fullcalendar

Comment: Does your element that can be dragged has the class `fc-event-draggable` ?